# How can I make a Spark paired RDD from many S3 files whose URLs are in an RDD?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have millions of S3 files, whose sizes average about 250k but are highly variable (up to a few 4 GB size).  I can't easily use wildcards to pick out multiple files, but I can make an RDD holding the S3 URLs of the files I want to process at any time.

I'd like to get two kinds of paired RDDs. The first would have the S3 URL, then the contents of the file as a Unicode string. (Is that even possible when some of the files can be so long?) The second could be computed from the first, by split()-ting the long string at newlines.

I've tried a number of ways to do this, typically getting a Python PicklingError, unless I iterate though the PII of S3 URLs one at a time. Then I can use union() to build up the big pairRDDs I want, as was described in another question. But I don't think that is going to run in parallel, which will be important when dealing with lots of files.

I'm currently using Python, but can switch to Scala or Java if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the files shouldn't matter as long as your cluster has the in-memory capacity. Generally, you'll need to do some [tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html) before everything works.

I'm not versed with python so I can't comment too much on pickling error. Perhaps these links might help but I'll add python tag so that someone better can take a look.

- [cloudpickle.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py)
- [pyspark serializer can't handle functions](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/pyspark-serializer-can-t-handle-functions-td7650.html)